# How can I easily add and remove message conversion logic into a processing flow in Spring Integration?

Tags: dynamic, spring-integration, type-conversion

I've been playing with Spring integration, and I can't see how best to solve the following problem.

Say I have XML messages arriving onto a channel. These messages may have arbitrary structure, and I want to convert them to my canonical form, so I think I want to write custom converters for each type of structure, so that I can do whatever processing and error-checking I want.

The obvious thing is to wire up a router to have a look at the messages and route to an appropriate converter, but I think this means I need to hard-code the processing flow onto a channel pointing at each converter.

I'd like to avoid hard-configuring in the different converters and routing logic, and the alternative that springs to mind is to have a set of converters that implement some kind of `boolean canHandle(message)`, so that we just show the message to each converter until one 'claims' the message or we run out. This way, it seems like I might be able to annotate the converters into the configuration without actually modifying the processing flow.

I'm new to Spring integration and I may well be mis-thinking this. Is there a stock way to do this in Spring integration, have I missed something or am I going about it all wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this. The first one that came to mind is a recipient list router with selector expressions:

```
<recipient-list-router id="simpleDynamicRouter" input-channel="simpleDynamicInput">
    <recipient selector-expression="@handler1.canHandle(payload)" channel="toHandler1"/>
    <recipient selector-expression="@handler2.canHandle(payload)" channel="toHandler2"/>
    <recipient selector-expression="@handler3.canHandle(payload)" channel="toHandler3"/>    
</recipient-list-router>

<transformer ... ref="handler1" />
<transformer ... ref="handler2" />
<transformer ... ref="handler3" />
```

Where handler1 etc are <bean/>s with your implementation, and canHandle() method.

Another option is to write your own custom dynamic router; there's an example of how to do that here https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-ftp